# Группировка и выборка данных в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Имеется Excel таблица следующего вида:

```
группа  запрос      .....   длстр

0       1 2 3 4 5 6           63
0       1 2 3 4 5             55
0       1 2 3 4 5 6           55
0       1 2 3 4               46
0       1 2 3 4               45
0       1 2 3 4               45
1       1 2 3 4 5 6           80
..
```

Имеются некоторая группа (в примере это группа - 0)

```
Среди группы необходимо получить только одну строку.
Условие выборки:
Если количество слов в столбце запрос = 5 выбираем, иначе
Если количество слов в столбце запрос = 6 выбираем, иначе если количество слов в столбце запрос равен 4 выбираем

Дополнительно, если встречаются несколько 5, 6 или 4, то нужно выбрать ту строчку, где значение в столбце длст ("G" в Excel) больше
```

В нашем случае выходная строчка, это

```
 группа  запрос      .....   длстр
    0    1 2 3 4 5             55
```

Кон

```
группа;Запрос;Позиция;Базовая частотность;Очень точная частотность;Количество слов;длстр
1;основные принципы демократического избирательного права таблица;47;12;12;6;63
1;основные принципы демократического избирательного права;39;148;14;5;55
1;порядок подачи жалобы на административное постановление;48;81;3;6;55
1;принципы демократического избирательного права;43;569;92;4;46
1;демократические принципы избирательного права;43;569;19;4;45
1;принцип демократического избирательного права;28;569;10;4;45
1;основные принципы избирательного права;45;745;111;4;38
1;принцип гласности избирательного права;50;21;1;4;38
1;принцип прямого избирательного права;50;368;56;4;36
1;принципы избирательного права это;49;285;44;4;33
1;принципы избирательного права;49;8504;1403;3;29
1;принцип избирательного права;38;8585;96;3;28
2;истечение срока давности уголовного преследования;40;553;28;5;49
2;срок давности по уголовным делам средней тяжести;48;46;15;7;48
2;срок исковой давности по уголовным преступлениям;42;30;12;6;48
2;как исчисляется срок давности по уголовным делам;10;19;15;7;48
2;когда истекает срок давности по уголовному делу;46;119;6;7;47
2;как считается срок давности по уголовным делам;6;9;1;7;46
2;срок давности для возбуждения уголовного дела;33;44;4;6;45
2;когда истекает срок давности уголовного дела;32;214;1;6;44
2;исчисление срока давности по уголовным делам;28;12;4;6;44
2;срок давности расследования уголовного дела;5;24;3;5;43
2;факт уголовного преследования срок хранения;35;19;3;5;43
2;что такое срок давности по уголовным делам;17;76;21;7;42
2;какие преступления не имеют срока давности;37;72;21;6;42
2;срок исковой давности в уголовном процессе;52;15;3;6;42
2;сроки исковой давности по уголовным делам;34;543;14;6;41
2;срок давности возбуждения уголовного дела;50;509;7;5;41
2;какой срок давности у тяжких преступлений;47;1;1;6;41
2;истечение срока давности уголовного дела;46;1536;17;5;40
2;срок давности по уголовным преступлениям;50;731;121;5;40
2;срок исковой давности по уголовным делам;36;556;171;6;40
2;срок исковой давности по уголовному делу;31;543;24;6;40
2;с какого момента начинается преступление;26;340;1;5;40
2;есть ли срок давности по уголовным делам;24;289;8;7;40
2;сколько срок давности по уголовным делам;32;52;9;6;40
2;сроки давности уголовного преследования;50;1063;49;4;39
2;какие сроки давности по уголовным делам;24;192;3;6;39
2;прошел срок давности по уголовным делам;28;40;4;6;39
2;какой срок давности по уголовным делам;28;187;12;6;38
2;преступления не имеющие срока давности;47;164;12;5;38
2;сроки преследования по уголовным делам;35;70;2;5;38
2;срок давности преступления сколько лет;49;43;2;5;38
2;срок исковой давности уголовного дела;34;711;18;5;37
2;срок преследования по уголовному делу;48;70;5;5;37
2;какой срок давности у уголовного дела;22;60;5;6;37
2;истечение срока давности преступления;49;11;11;4;37
2;какие статьи не имеют срока давности;39;16;2;6;36
2;исковая давность по уголовным делам;28;630;21;5;35
2;когда истекает срок уголовного дела;27;407;6;5;35
2;какой срок уголовного преследования;50;76;1;4;35
2;какой срок давности у уголовных дел;22;56;27;6;35
2;срок исковой давности по уголовным;37;586;2;5;34
2;срок давности в уголовном процессе;38;65;2;5;34
2;сроки давности по уголовным делам;47;5885;468;5;33
2;сроки давности по уголовному делу;43;5773;19;5;33
2;по каким делам нет срока давности;51;18;1;6;33
2;срок давности по уголовным делам;48;5885;1778;5;32
2;срок давности по уголовному делу;43;5773;41;5;32
2;какой срок давности преступления;51;501;4;4;32
2;какие статьи имеют срок давности;24;22;2;5;32
2;давность лет по уголовным делам;18;118;6;5;31
2;срок истечения уголовного дела;34;2030;7;4;30
2;сроки уголовного преследования;32;1519;36;3;30
2;срок действия уголовной статьи;54;22;1;4;30
2;срок давности уголовного дела;29;8239;86;4;29
2;срок уголовного преследования;39;1519;27;3;29
2;срок действия уголовного дела;23;357;5;4;29
2;срок годности уголовного дела;32;41;7;4;29
2;срок давности уголовных дел;23;8056;24;4;27
2;сроки давности по уголовным;45;7877;30;4;27
2;сроки давности преступлений;50;7309;61;3;27
2;давность по уголовным делам;28;6019;5;4;27
2;срок действия уголовных дел;30;357;2;4;27
2;срок давности по уголовным;39;7877;39;4;26
2;срок давности преступление;49;7456;5;3;26
2;срок действия преступлений;30;224;3;3;26
2;срок действия преступления;36;222;10;3;26
2;срок годности преступления;39;16;16;3;26
2;давность уголовного дела;25;8321;2;3;24
2;срок давности дела;49;17016;6;3;18
20;как сделать лицензию на такси самому;34;33;6;6;36
22;уголовный кодекс об оскорблении личности человка;43;5;2;6;40
22;моральное оскорбление личности статья;37;44;6;4;37
26;образец жалобы на неправильно поставленный диагноз врача;33;1;1;7;56
26;врачи поставили неправильный диагноз куда жаловаться;17;36;4;6;52
26;если поставили неправильный диагноз куда жаловаться;12;57;4;6;51
26;врачи неправильно поставили диагноз куда обращаться;22;12;1;6;51
26;кому жаловаться на неправильно поставленный диагноз;17;3;1;6;51
26;если врач поставил неправильный диагноз что делать;44;51;19;7;50
26;врач поставил неправильный диагноз куда жаловаться;11;36;12;6;50
26;жалоба на неправильно поставленный диагноз образец;27;1;1;6;50
26;поставили неправильный диагноз куда жаловаться;7;57;3;5;46
26;куда жаловаться на неправильный диагноз врача;5;3;1;6;45
26;жалоба на неправильно поставленный диагноз;16;18;1;5;42
26;поставили неправильный диагноз что делать;50;96;2;5;41
26;если врач назначил неправильное лечение;37;42;7;5;39
26;куда жаловаться на неправильный диагноз;11;8;1;5;39
26;если врач неправильно поставил диагноз;51;407;4;5;38
26;неправильный диагноз врачей что делать;44;82;7;5;38
26;неправильный диагноз куда обращаться;24;71;1;4;36
26;жалоба на врача неправильный диагноз;9;31;1;5;36
26;если врач неверно поставил диагноз;46;84;3;5;34
26;врач написал неправильный диагноз;43;26;1;4;33
26;жалоба на неверный диагноз врача;9;9;4;5;32
26;если врач поставил неправильный;46;469;1;4;31
26;врач поставил ошибочный диагноз;49;114;1;4;31
26;жалобы на неправильный диагноз;21;71;1;4;30
```

Выходные данные (если сам не ошибся)

```
1 - 1;основные принципы демократического избирательного права;39;148;14;5;55
2 - 2;истечение срока давности уголовного преследования;40;553;28;5;49
20 - 20;как сделать лицензию на такси самому;34;33;6;6;36
22 - 22;уголовный кодекс об оскорблении личности человка;43;5;2;6;40
26 - 26;поставили неправильный диагноз куда жаловаться;7;57;3;5;46
```

Comment: @MaxU добавил выходную строчку

Comment: @MaxU отредактировал

Comment: @MaxU сконвертировал Excel в csv и вытащил некоторые наборы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def get_indices(d):
    ord_map = {5:100, 6:90, 4:80}
    tmp = d["Запрос"].str.split().str.len().map(ord_map).fillna(0).values
    # print(d.assign(x=tmp))
    return d.assign(x=tmp).nlargest(1, ["x", "длстр"]).index[0]

res = df.loc[df.groupby("группа").apply(get_indices)]
```

---

результат:

```
In [41]: res
Out[41]:
    группа                                             Запрос  Позиция  Базовая частотность  Очень точная частотность  Количество слов  длстр
1        1  основные принципы демократического избирательн...       39                  148                        14                5     55
12       2  истечение срока давности уголовного преследования       40                  553                        28                5     49
81      20               как сделать лицензию на такси самому       34                   33                         6                6     36
82      22   уголовный кодекс об оскорблении личности человка       43                    5                         2                6     40
92      26     поставили неправильный диагноз куда жаловаться        7                   57                         3                5     46
```

Comment: вроде правильно, а не посоветуйте как представить набор данных в виде двумерного массива? Обычно с pandas не работаю. for r in res: выдает только название столбцов

Comment: @danilshik, если хотите задать новый вопрос - откройте пожалуйста новый SO вопрос ;)

Comment: @danilshik, [df.iterrows()](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows) - но итерирование по строкам DataFrame - один из самых медленных способов работы с данными...

Comment: мне необходимы 2 первых столбца, которые будут обрабатываться корутинами, не думаю что async умеет с dataset работать

Comment: @danilshik, лучше задать новый вопрос с небольшим пояснением что вы хотите сделать, для чего и что получить на выходе... Что должны делать "корутины"? Лучшим подходом при работе с данными в DataFrame'ах - это использование векторизированных (быстрых) функций. Объяснять это в комментариях - не самый лучший вариант...